# Get Text from various EditText fields

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-edittext

In my Android App that where i use Java in Android Studio I want to use a loop to get the inserted Texts from my EditText fields

Could you please help me?

```
for (int i=0; i==player; i++ ){
     myArray[i] = "player"+i.getText().toString();
}
```

I have EditTextfields which can be declared as player0 until player15.
And Player is my total amount of EditTextfields.

I want to write all the inputs into an array but i get always an error for the part`"player"+i`" is there an other solution how to handle that?

Comment: `i` is an `int` and won’t have a `getText()` method. Also check if `i==player` is what you want in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Java does not work that way. You can't generate a variable name from a string.
The easiest way to get what you want is an array.

```
EditText[] players = {
    player0, player1, player2, player3, player4, 
    player5, player6, player7, player8, player9, 
    player10, player11, player12, player13, player14, player15
};
List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>(players.length);
for (EditText player : players) {
    texts.add(players[i].getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: -1 Instead you should use the views instead of separating the views and the text associated with them. Makes it easier to deal with.

Comment: @JoxTraex yes, unless the user has finished filling the form and you want to collect the inputs and submit them. After all, you'll need to actually get the text out of the view at some point.

Answer (score 0):

if you have all the edit text fields in the same layout (Linear layout....)
you can simply access every EditText using a loop by accessing them as childs of the layout
suppose in the xml file you have a linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

notice that we gave the layout an id (linearLayout)
now from your java code you can simply populate the array by using the following loop

```
    LinearLayout linear= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    for(int i=0;i<linear.getChildCount();i++)
    {
      EditText field=linear.getChildAt(i);
      array[i]=field.getText().toString();
    }
```

unlike the method you are trying to use this method is more dynamic where you dont have to provide ids for all the editTexts just a single id for your main layout and you would not have to declare a static array with all the ids in your java code